# why process initially runs in kernel mode

Tags: process, operating-system

Why does a process created by fork first runs in Kernel mode and then in user mode? Why does it not run directly in user mode?  What problems will occur if dispatcher directly runs it in user mode?

Here is the image link: [UNIX Process State Transition Diagram](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/23940071/Figure-315-UNIX-Process-State-Transition-Diagram)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `fork` is (at the lowest level) a system call that executes in kernel space.

One process goes into kernel mode (as part of the `fork`) and two come out. That means one of them must have started in there :-)